# qSqlQueryModel with SQL server with custom class

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to make an application which is completely based on SQL server. After 5 months with my project I realized that my application structure is wrong while I tried to use 'qSqlQueryModel' with qtableView.so I need an expert solutions to make an application systematically arrange. I tried many approaches and read docs as well. But don't know where I did wrong.

I used Designer to create layout. Here is my project Structure:

```
Application
          |---connection
          |            |----connection.py
          |
          |---CSS ---css.py
          |
          |---EventHandler----acc_EventHandler.py
          |
          |---InterFaces ----acc_layout.py (converted from .ui)
          |
          |---Resources
          |           |--fonts
          |           |--icons
          |           |--qrc
          |
          |__mainApp.py
          |
          |__acc_view.py
```

When application is open db connection is created .after db connection established user can search the value from the inpput method from the form. This is completely query based application and I use tabWidget for different approaches. I have many layouts which I stored in `Interfaces` folder like acc_layout.py and acc_EventHandler.py is the corresponding file where I wrote SQL queries separately.`acc_view.py` is the view part.

This is my code part, which may be wrong:

**acc_view.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QPushButton,QMenu,QTableWidgetItem
import resources.qrc_account
import resources.qrc_billing
import sys
from files.interfaces.acc_layout import Ui_BillingWindow
from event_handler.acc_Eenthandler import *
from css.billing_css import * 
from connection.connection import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery,QSqlTableModel,QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex, Qt

class MyTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
def __init__(self, table_data, parent=None):
    QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.table_data = table_data

def rowCount(self, parent,QModelIndex_parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
    return len(self.table_data)

def columnCount(self, parent):
    return len(self.table_data[0])

def flags(self, index):
    original_flags = super(MyTableModel, self).flags(index)
    return original_flags | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        item = index.internalPointer()
        if item is not None:
            print(item)
        value = self.table_data[row][column]
        return value

 class accMainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget,Ui_BillingWindow):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(billingMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
   
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet(stylesheet2)
    self.pushButton_FeeTran.clicked.connect(self.insightAccountCall)<----self function call


def insightAccountCall(self):
    print("Loading insight Account datas...")    
    
    input_value=self.account_lineEdit.text()
    type_value=str(self.account_comboBox.currentText())

    self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
   
    data=loadInsightAccount(input_value,type_value) <-----function call loadInsightAccount from acc_Eventhandler
    print(data)
    self.model = MyTableModel(data)
    self.tableView.setModel(self.model)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = accMainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**acc_eventHandler.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from  PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def loadInsightAccount(input_value,type_value):

    print(input_value)
    print(type_value)

            if type_value=="Account Number":
        print("Account Number")
        
        query_string="SELECT  convert(int,iinsightaccountid) as AccountID, *  from InsightAccounts.dbo.InsightAccount(nolock) where vchCustodianAccountNumber like"+"'%"+ input_value +"%'"
        # print(query_string)

        InsightAcc_data=displayData(query_string) <--call function displayData from connection.py

        return (InsightAcc_data)
```

**connection.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication,QMessageBox, QLabel
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer

def onActivated(self,text):
   
    createConnection(self, text)

USERNAME = ''
PASSWORD = ''
DATABASE = ''

def selectedServer(server):
    switcher = {
        'TFUS3 (UAT)': 'DESKTOP-4TB7NOA',
        'TFUSD (test)': '8888888888888',
    }
    return switcher.get(server, "Invalid Server ")

def createConnection(self, server):

    SERVER = selectedServer(server)
    global db
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC')
    db.setDatabaseName(f'Driver={{SQL SERVER}}; Server={SERVER}; UID={USERNAME}; PWD={PASSWORD};')
    if db.open():
        print(f'{server} Server connected successfully')
        # qApp.setStyleSheet("QMessageBox {background-color: #364392;}")
        
        QMessageBox.about(self, 'Connection',f'{server} Server connected successfully')
        # QMessageBox.information(self, 'Notification', 'connected', QMessageBox.Ok) 
        return True
    else:
        print(f'{server} connection failed')
        return False

def displayData(sqlStatement):
    print('processing query...')
    qry = QSqlQuery(db)
    qry.prepare(sqlStatement)
    print(sqlStatement)
    qry.exec()
    # result = cursor.fetchall() 

    model = QSqlQueryModel()
    model.setQuery(qry)
  
    return model  <---may be wrong approach
```

I know I used too much function call which make hard to understand.

Comment: First of all, please fix the indentation on your code excerpts (see [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)). Then, what is the reason behind splitting so many related and orphaned functions into so many files? It really doesn't help performance nor project design, and it only makes maintenance really troublesome. Also, there are many functions that refer to `self`, but they don't seem to be part of a class. What is the need behind that?

Comment: @musicamante thanks for your valuable suggestions.i will concern about formatting code.can you please show me a perfect example of qSqlQueryModel with custom class where db connection and view is in two different file.